# JSoup or XPath for Web-scraping?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, xpath, jsoup

How would JSoup benefit me more so than XPath if extracting websites for content such as images and text? Or is XPath the better choice in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| Advantage | XPath | JSoup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Handles well-formed markup | ✅ | ✅ |
| Handles poorly formed markup |  | ✅ |
| Has clean, declarative syntax | ✅ |  |
| Is standardized | ✅ |  |
| **Supported by hosting language:** Java | ✅ | ✅ |
| **Supported by hosting language and utilities:** C#, JavaScript, Python, PhP, VBA, Ruby, XSLT, xmlstarlet | ✅ |  |